# Building jqm listview programmatically, icons for each list item not populating

Tags: jquery, json, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm building a listview with nested listviews inside it based on some json I'm getting from a web service call. The code below shows how I'm trying to build the first listview, but I'm not getting my icons that are supposed to show up on creation. Also, I'm wanting to add list items each with a  property for each customer, but having trouble getting them to append. If someone can look at this and see what I'm missing, I'd appreciate it.

This is inside an ajax success event:

```
var customerList = data.adminCustomerList;
                $.each(customerList, function(i, value) {
                    $('#custList').append('<li id=" + value.custCode + InfoList" data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-inset="false"><h2>' + value.custCode + '</h2></li>');
                    $('#cust' + value.custCode).append('<ul id="' + value.custCode + 'Properties" data-role="listview"></ul>');
                    $.each(customerList, function(i, value) {
                        //TODO: add each customer property in an append.
                    });
                });
                $('#custList').listview('refresh');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pgIndex">
<div data-role="header" class="text-center">
    Customer Index
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="mainDiv">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="custList">

    </ul>
</div>
```

Sample json code returning from web service:

```
  "adminCustomerList": [
{
  "custId": xxxxx,
  "custCode": "customer name",
  "custName": "even more text",
  "custDescr": "more text",
  "createdDate": "text",
  "custUserList": [{...}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dom element ids, you cannot have spaces, so make sure custCode never has spaces, or use custId instead.

In this line:

```
'<li id=" + value.custCode + InfoList" ...
```

you are missing some quotes. It should be

```
'<li id="' + value.custCode + 'InfoList" ...
```

In this line

```
$('#cust' + value.custCode).append('<ul id=
```

You are building a different selector. Is it value.custCode + 'InfoList' or 'cust' + value.custCode?

call .enhanceWithin() on the outer listview as well as listview("refresh"), so that inner lists and collapsibles are enhanced.

Code should be something like:

```
var customerList = data.adminCustomerList;
$.each(customerList, function(i, value) {
    $('#custList').append('<li id="cust' + value.custId + '" data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-inset="false"><h2>' + value.custCode + '</h2></li>');
    $('#cust' + value.custId).append('<ul id="' + value.custId + 'Properties" data-role="listview"></ul>');
    var $ul = $('#' + value.custId + 'Properties')
    var customerProps = value.custUserList;
    $.each(customerProps, function(idx, cval) {
        $ul.append('<li>' + cval.prop + '</li>');
    });
});
$('#custList').listview('refresh').enhanceWithin();
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gup7xc5w/)**